# Landscape layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Can i handle size of item in xml file when i'm in portrait or landscape mode?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "handle" ? If you have 2 layouts, one for portrait and one for landscape then you can change the size of an item in the xml file - so long as you respond to the rotation correctly and change your layout then you should be ok

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can create two xml layout files for that activity and place them in layout and layout-land folders respectively. Then the system will automatically take the proper layout for the proper orientation.